# Flagging a query string in htaccess and retrieving it in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\?(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [ENV=HASQSTRING:1]

# miscellaneous rewriterules to redirect pages. 
# No environment variables changed here
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    echo "QS=".$_ENV['HASQSTRING'];
?>
```

and I even tried this PHP code:

```
<?php
    echo "QS=".$_SERVER['HASQSTRING'];
?>
```

I receive this result each time:

```
Notice: Undefined index: HASQSTRING in (php filename) on line 2
```

and the URL's I'm testing with always has a query string to it such as:

```
http://localhost.local/?a=1
http://localhost.local/?a=1&b=2
http://localhost.local/help/?a=1&b=2
```

How do I fix my .htaccess so that when a query string is present in the original URL (not in the internal redirected url that mod_rewrite generates) the value of HASQSTRING equals 1?

I have tried checking the value of REDIRECT_STATUS, but it always wants to return a value of 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HASQSTRING:%1]
```

Then inside PHP code use

```
<?php
    echo "QS=" . $_SERVER['HASQSTRING'];
?>
```